# SSLProtocolException after parsing CSV lines

Tags: android, ssl, bufferedreader, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm downloading a set of CSV lines to my android device through a simple `HTTP/GET` request via an SSL connection. This worked like a charm until we switch to a new server (Debian 6 -> Debian 7), this may be an issue with the server certificate but I don't think so because the download starts and is parsing about 700 articles before this exception is thrown on `.readLine()`:

(Note that the download have been tested on Android ICS (4.*) and works without any issues, it seems to only affect Android <= 2.3.)

```
Read error: ssl=0x35e700: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0x35e700: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:788)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:161)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:255)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:128)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:357)
    at xx.xxxxx.services.ArticlesSync.doInBackground(ArticlesSync.java:155)
    at xx.xxxxx.services.ArticlesSync.doInBackground(ArticlesSync.java:26)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

|

```
InputStream inputStream = response.getContent();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

String currentLine = null;
SQLArticleManager articles = SQLArticleManager.createArticles();
while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    if (!progressDialog.isShowing())
    {
        return ERROR_ABORTED;
    }

    String[] data = currentLine.split("`");

    if (data.length == 4)
    {
        articles.addArticle(data[0], data[1], data[2], Float.parseFloat(data[3]));
    }

    rowsRead++;
    publishProgress(createProgress((int) (rowsRead * 100 / rows), ""));
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Can it be due to a timeout somewhere?

Comment: Aside: You said it was a CSV, but then are splitting by not a comma, looks like a '`'?

Comment: The column separator is set to `, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but this is a known Android bug affecting versions 2.2-2.3.3 (API levels 9 & 10). [See this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15503) and also [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16121&can=1&q=sslexception&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) for more details.

There's a [further discussion](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10807#c30) documenting that this may be an issue with regards to root CA, but the 2nd link there conflicts with this data, so I do not believe this is the case.

What I believe works (though I haven't mocked up a quick sample to verify) is to explicitly use a 4k buffer in conjunction with `getInputStream()`, i.e.

```
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You mean 'new BufferedReader(..., 4096)'? That's the default.

Comment: Incorrect, the default is double that, 8k, 8192 bytes. Check the default constructor here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: Thanks @Mike. I tried changing the buffer size but no cigar. At least now I know it's a known bug.